# Volume and brightness keys not working in Xfce

Tags: 14.04, brightness, xfce

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 and when I was working with Unity, everything was fine but then I switched to Xfce and now the keyboard shortcuts for brightness and volume control are not working. I've tried the methods given in other posts for volume but they didn't work for me. Also, i have to fix the brightness everytime I log in.

Answer (score 2):

Xfce4 has a package `xfce4-mixer` for mixer setting. You need to install it. (for example, using `sudo apt install xfce4-mixer`) Then install `xfce4-volumed` that actually gives you control to change volume using multimedia keys.

To configure `xfce4-mixer`, open it (use command `xfce4-mixer`) and choose your sound card. Then choose tracks (eg. Master or Headphone). Now try to change volume.